# Is passing the Acid3 test important?

Tags: browser, standards

I use Firefox for my primary browser but I've noticed it doesn't completely pass the Acid3 test.

Well I know that most sites will still continue to work even though my browser isn't 100% standards-compliant.

Is passing the Acid3 test important? Should I be using a browser that uses Webkit?

Comment: just as a side note, Firefox 12.0 passes with 100/100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always believed that passing any test is only truly a measure of the ability to pass that test - extrapolating to other abilities is dangerous. This is also true of these Acid tests. What matters in a web browser is the ability to view the websites you want to view without any problems, not the ability to jump through hoops like this. A browser with a good score is likely to render most sites pretty well, but then so do some with low scores.

FWIW, my copy of FireFox scores 72/100 which is pretty good. My copy of IE6 scores 12/100, yet a very significant portion of the world use this browser every day without real problems.

Comment: Much to the chagrin of developers everywhere...

Comment: Passing a test such as the Acid test is much more than just "a measure of the ability to pass that test."  The Acid test describes web *standards*.  If a browser does not pass that test, it's doing something wrong.  It's as simple as that.  The Acid test will tell you how correctly or how incorrectly your browser displays websites, based on what the simple rules say it *should* be.

The fact that a significant portion of the world uses IE without problems is because people IGNORE the Acid test and force honest developers to break rules so that things show properly in a faulty browser.

Comment: wow... Microsoft hasn't really done much better with their more recent ones either. IE 8 (the latest version that will run on XP) only scores 14/100

Answer (score 6):

No, your browser passing the Acid 3 test isn't important for your average web browsing (or web development).  The acid tests are designed to give browsers a benchmark to test their compatibility with cutting-edge web standards.  Switching browsers to one the pass Acid 3 would have add no net benefit to your internet experience.

That said, Firefox 3.5 scores respectably (90/100 here).

Answer (score 2):

No. Acid3 is a goal or benchmark for browsers; it tests compatibility with the latest standards. Most sites/apps are designed to be cross-browser, often supporting different versions of each browser, any way. So those new features won't even be utilised for years after all major browsers pass.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you notice sites breaking on you.  It hasn't really been much of an issue and I think more than anything its a warning signal from W3C to browser vendors that "hey: your browser isn't standards compliant!  fall in line, please, or people will not use your browser.."